# Can I evaluate variable in predicate apply method？

Tags: java, guava

I  recently work on a project that heavily using  collection filter function provided by Guava,but I found something like this won't  produce the expected behavior:

```
  Predicate<ProductClassDTO> secLevelPredicate = new Predicate<ProductClassDTO>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(ProductClassDTO pcLevel2) {

      if (pcLevel2.getFatherNodeSid() != null)
        return pcLevel2.getFatherNodeSid() == dto.getSid();
      else
        return false;
    }
  };
```

dto object is an object in the outer loop but still reachable.

The return of that apply method is never get out with True,but if I replace the dto.getSid() with the real number like 1740 which is a father node number get from db, the outcome is fine.

So I figure that I can not evaluate variable in apply()?

I notice [apply()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release09/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html#line.45) javadoc has a line saying :

> Its execution does not cause any observable side effects

Should this be the key to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be fine - although `dto` will need to be a final variable if this is within a method and `dto` is a local variable.

Is it possible that `dto.getSid()` returns an `Integer` and the problem is that it's just comparing the references instead of values? You may be able to make the code neater *and* correct just by using:

```
@Override
public boolean apply(ProductClassDTO pcLevel2) {
  return Objects.equal(pcLevel2.getFatherNodeSid(), dto.getSid());
}
```

Comment: yes,I forgot I am using Integer instead of values, everything is just fine, and the improvement you gave it here is much valuable.Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having your `final` variable read inside of your anonymous class, you're better off limiting scope as much as possible, and not forcing scope to "bleed" with `final` variables.

In fact, the Guava designers anticipated this, and want you to avoid using `final` variables in this way, and gave you the tools to avoid it. In this case, it is a combination of `Predicates.equalTo` and `Predicates.compose`. I think what you're looking for is:

```
Predicate<ProductClassDTO> secLevelPredicate = Predicates.compose(
    Predicates.equalTo(dto.getSid()),
    new Function<ProductClassDTO, Long>() {
        public Long apply(ProductClassDTO pcLevel2) {
            return pcLevel2.getFatherNodeSid();
        }
    }
);
```